# Simultaneous diagonalization of self adjoint matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

If U and T are self adjoint linear operators on finite dimensional real I nner product space which commute with each other then there is an orthonormal basis for V consisting of vectors that are eigenvectors of both U and T.
Hi!
Please help me with this problem.
It is problem no 14 , chapter 6.4 in Linear Algebra Book by Friedberg, Insel and Spence.
Hint that is given is to use the an eigenspace of T is U invariant as well. But I don't know how to proceed further to get a basis consisting of eigenvectors of both U and T.
Does T and U have same set of eigenvectors? I am really not getting what is going on.

Comment: The key is to prove that each eigenspace of $U$ is stable under $T$.

Comment: Yup. That I could prove. But I guess I am missing something on how to proceed with that fact. If eigenspace of U is stable under T that does not imply that U and T are going to have same eigenvectors.

Comment: see https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_6-4-14?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 5):

If $U$ and $T$ are commuting linear operators, they will preserve each other's eigenspaces. The proof is short: If $Uv = \lambda v$, then $U(Tv) = T(Uv) = T( \lambda v) = \lambda(Tv)$. Since in your case $U$ and $T$ are self-adjoint, the operators will be diagonalisable, with real eigenvalues.

So, first take the eigenspace $V_\lambda$ of $U$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Since $V_\lambda$ is stable under $T$, the restriction  $T|_{V_\lambda}$ is a self-adjoint operator on $V_\lambda$. Now, by the spectral theorem $V_\lambda$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $T|_{V_\lambda}$, say $(v_1, \ldots, v_r)$ corresponding to eigenvalues $\mu_1, \ldots, \mu_r$ respectively. Going back up to the whole space $V$, we have produced the first part of a simultaneous diagonalisation: $Uv_i = \lambda v_{i}$ and $T v_{i} = \mu_i v_i$ for each $i$.

Now, repeat this process for every different eigenspace of $U$, and collect together each group of vectors you find. Finally, use the fact that $U$ is self-adjoint (which we haven't really used yet) to conclude that this collection is mutually orthogonal, and spans $V$.

Comment: Wow. This is great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer! It seems that the latter part of the hint is not used... Sometimes the textbook gives some useless hints but readers are usually aware of it after they read the solution.